# Combine letters of a string with a given number of siblings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, permutation, permute

With a given string I need to combine the chars of the word only with a certain number of siblings, i.e., `Hello` with 3, the combinations will be: `Hel`, `ell`, `llo`.

a was trying with the combination and permutation function, but I can't control how the function combines the chars.

Comment: You should include what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```py
> >>> def substrings(s, length=3):
> ...     yield from (s[i:i + length] for i in range(len(s) - length + 1))
> ...
> >>>
> >>> list(substrings("Hello"))
> ['Hel', 'ell', 'llo']
> >>> list(substrings("Hello", length=2))
> ['He', 'el', 'll', 'lo']
> >>> list(substrings("Hello", length=5))
> ['Hello']
> >>> list(substrings("Hello", length=6))
> []
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can just walk across the string indexes and ignore the last couple indexes that will be too short in length

```
>>> foo = 'hello'
>>> [foo[i:i+3] for i, _ in enumerate(foo) if i+2 < len(foo)]
['hel', 'ell', 'llo']
```